# Create dynamic index for array of object jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

```js
var menu = [];
$('.mainmenu').click(function() {
  $('.mainmenu').each(function(i,v) {

    var sub = {};
    var indexmenu = $(this).attr('id');
    sub[indexmenu] = $(this).attr('data-currstate');
    menu.push(sub);

  })
  $.each(menu,function(i,v) {
    console.log(i)
    console.log(v)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a target="_top" href="#" class='mainmenu' id='maintenance' data-currstate='hide'>
  <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Maintenance
</a>
```

I want to create an array of object from a menu wherein I want the ID of each menu to be the index and the value will be state.

1. I want the id of each menu to be the index and the state to be the value
2. What i get is the id and value becomes the value

`Note`:

In my actual code the creation of the menu array happens on load of page in demo I created it on click. Also the reason why I created on load is that I store the value in local storage. I made the demo as simple as I can

Comment: Can you please add an example of expected output?

Comment: @Justcode in the console log I want to get `maintenance` as index instead of `0`and `hide` as value instead of `{"maintenance":"value"}`

Comment: You mean this `{  "0": "hide" }`?

Comment: I believe @guradio want 0 (i) as `maintenance`

Comment: Mukyuu is correct I want 0 to be maintenance

Comment: @guradio then should you not use `menu` as object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of object.

This is a part of ES6, so you will have browser compatibility issues. You can check [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility).

ES6 introduced 2 new classes: Map and Set, which are similar to Array and Objects, but with 1 major difference. Their `keys` can be anything. So you can have array index as non-numeric values as well. If you want them to be unique, you can look into `Set`.

```js
var menu = new Map();
$('.mainmenu').click(function() {
  $('.mainmenu').each(function(i,v) {
    menu.set($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('data-currstate'));
  })
  for( const [k, v] of menu.entries()) {
    console.log(`Key: ${k} | Value: ${v}`)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a target="_top" href="#" class='mainmenu' id='maintenance' data-currstate='hide'>
  <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Maintenance
</a>
```

Comment: this is what I wanted can you add a bit more explanation please

Comment: happy coding mate

Comment: @guradio Please check the update. Hope it answers your queries